Filter out a few elements from Map efficiently
In my code I have identified the following line which performs slower than I expected:
val newItems = items.view.filterKeys(predicate).toMap

When profiling, the toMap calls Map.from which calls MapBuilderImpl.addAll(IterableOnce), which I think is an evidence the map is fully rebuilt.
There was a Map.filterKeys which is deprecated now, and even if it was not, its result was a view anyway. Its deprecation comment says:

Use .view.filterKeys(f). A future version will include a strict version of this method (for now, .view.filterKeys(p).toMap)

There are many items. The predicate leaves most of them present, it just discards a few of them. I would like to reuse the map information as much as possible and I hoped filterKeys will allow me to do this.
Is there an efficient way to build a Map from a MapView or some other efficient way how to filter out a few elements from a strict Map?

It seems your best option for now is to use the MapView directly. - I would suggest making an issue on [scala-library-next] requesting that in the future there should be both strict and lazy versions of filterKeys and mapValues

I do not think this is a solution for me. The items variable is a part of state which is long lived and gradually evolving. I am not sure, but it seems strange to keep chain of .view.filterKeys and to work with it. It seems the most practical option will be to use items -- items.keys.filterNot(predicate) to discard just some entries.

Issue created at https://github.com/scala/scala-library-next/issues/176

Then it seems you just want to write a small view over a mutable Map.

It might be faster to construct a VectorMap: val newItems = VectorMap.from(map.view.filterKeys(predicate))

The most efficient way I have found is:
items -- items.keys.filterNot(predicate)

